# Dagger 2 : How to bind Fragment Map in parent component from subcomponent for FragmentFactory

Tags: android, android-fragments, dagger-2, dagger

I have this Dagger 2 configuration:

**AppComponent.kt**

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        AppModule::class,
        ActivityBindingModule::class,
    ]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<AppApplication> {
    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<AppApplication>()
}
```

**ActivityBindingModule.kt**

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBindingModule {
    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(
        modules = [
            MainActivityModule::class,
            FragmentModule::class //a fragment factory for each activity
        ]
    )
    internal abstract fun mainActivity(): MainActivity
}
```

**MainActivityModule.kt**

```
@Module(subcomponents = [LoginFragmentSubcomponent::class])
abstract class MainActivityModule {
    //uncommenting this works fine but Fragment can't be scoped
    //@Binds
    //@IntoMap
    //@FragmentKey(LoginFragment::class)
    //abstract fun bindLoginFragment(loginFragment: LoginFragment): Fragment

    //...other things which work fine
}

@Subcomponent(modules = [LoginFragmentModule::class])
@FragmentScoped
interface LoginFragmentSubcomponent : AndroidInjector<LoginFragment> {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<LoginFragment>()
}

@Module
abstract class LoginFragmentModule {
    //this can't be seen from Map used in DefaultFragmentFactory
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @FragmentKey(LoginFragment::class)
    abstract fun bindLoginFragment(loginFragment: LoginFragment): Fragment
}
```

**FragmentModule.kt**

```
@Module
abstract class FragmentModule {
    @Binds
    internal abstract fun bindFragmentFactory(factory: DefaultFragmentFactory): FragmentFactory
}
```

**DefaultFragmentFactory.kt**

```
@ActivityScoped
class DefaultFragmentFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val creators: Map<Class<out Fragment>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<Fragment>>
) : FragmentFactory() {
    //this is deprecated in fragment-ktx 1.1.0-alpha06 
    //but you need to override this if you were using the bundle
    override fun instantiate(classLoader: ClassLoader, className: String, args: Bundle?): Fragment {
        return instantiate(classLoader, className).apply { arguments = args }
    }
    override fun instantiate(classLoader: ClassLoader, className: String): Fragment {
        val fragmentClass = loadFragmentClass(classLoader, className)
        val found = creators.entries.find { fragmentClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key) }
        val provider = found?.value
        //if we don't find a match in the map, proceed with the default empty constructor
        return if (provider != null) {
            provider.get()
        } else {
            fragmentClass.newInstance()
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is to use the `FragmentFactory` to create the `Fragments`.
As described in the code, I can uncomment this lines:

```
@Binds
@IntoMap
@FragmentKey(LoginFragment::class)
abstract fun bindLoginFragment(loginFragment: LoginFragment): Fragment
```

and removing everything connected to `LoginFragmentSubcomponent` and the injection is working fine.

The problem with this approach is that the Fragment can't be scoped properly, in a way that if the Fragment is destroyed all the child Fragments below are destroyed which will force the Factory to create a new instance at the next call.

So I've decided to add a `Subcomponent` called LoginFragmentSubcomponent to be able to define the `@FragmentScoped` on it. 
Now the problem is that from the module `LoginFragmentModule` I can't contribute to the parent `Map` I need in `DefaultFragmentFactory` which is of type:

```
Map<Class<out Fragment>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<Fragment>>
```

In fact the error I'm receiving at compile time is:

```
[Dagger/MissingBinding] 
java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment>,
javax.inject.Provider<androidx.fragment.app.Fragment>> cannot be provided 
without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

**Here there is a sample repo with the reproducible problem**: https://github.com/matpag/dagger-test-fragmentfactory

**Is there a solution to this?**

Using Dagger 2.21

Thanks in advance

> PS: The idea behind this `FragmentFactory` injection came from this
>   awesome post:
>   https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/using-androidxs-fragmentfactory-with-dagger-for-fragment-dependency-injection I just tweaked it a bit.

Comment: Apparently a possible solution has been posted [here](https://medium.com/@nlg.tuan.kiet/fragmentfactory-and-how-to-maintain-scoping-with-dagger-2-d9d16c892626). I still not consider this an answer because the "solution" is too complex to be acceptable in my opinion... (let's wait to see alternatives and more easy solutions)

Comment: Another option is this [article](https://proandroiddev.com/constructor-injection-into-fragments-with-respect-of-scopes-311c0258d678) which also shows how to scope your dependencies. I also think this is a little hacky-ish but it's not too bad.

Comment: @Sphig316 thanks for pointing out the article! Yes... it's still hacky IMO. I will wait until the new announced Dagger will come out before using FragmentFactory or move to service locators like Koin

Comment: @MatPag, were u able to sort the issue, as i am also stuck in the issue,  I don't think tis link, is working for nested subcomponents,https://proandroiddev.com/constructor-injection-into-fragments-with-respect-of-scopes-311c0258d678

Comment: @Reprator Nope, this has no solution currently :( 
FragmentFactory is still not supported in Dagger and the new Hilt. I've read here: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1893 that there are technical limits for this.